# How to override LOGGER interface default implementation

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am using final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz); to get the LOGGER object of org.slf4j. I am facing difficulty in overriding any default implemented method of this class.

I am trying to override non-static method of the conrete class. Lets say, Class MyLogger { Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz); LOGGER.debug("Some message"); } Now debug method is the non-static method declared in the LOGGER class for which some concrete implementation has been provided. The problem here is I am seeing lots of implementation classes when I try to search for the references. So in order to override debug method what should I do

Updated the original class like this:

```
public class MyLogger implements Logger {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogger.class);
 public static org.slf4j.Logger init(Class clazz) {
        final Logger loggerOut = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
        setContainerId();
        LOGGER.debug("Logger is initialized for [{}].", clazz.getName());
        return loggerOut;
    }


    public void debug(String msg, Object arg1)
    {
        LOGGER.debug("My message",arg1);
    }
}
```

Still not able to get result. Please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and improve your question accordingly (i.e. Why do want to override methods? What methods exactly? What is your best approach that did not work as expected (show code)? What were the errors you got?). As is, we cannot deduct any problem you are having and are thus unable to actually help you.

Comment: ... and also a little tip: Better describe what goal it is that you want to achieve and then lay out your failed attempt. That way people can give answers regarding the actual problem, instead of fixing a potentially flawed approach. (See "x-y-Problem")

Answer (score 0):

Static methods cannot be overriden. If you see  [here](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html#getLogger(java.lang.Class)) the functions of LoggerFactory in documentation

Comment: I am trying to override non-static method of the implementation class. Lets say, Class MyLogger {
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
LOGGER.debug("Some message");
}
Now debug method is the non-static method declared in the LOGGER class for which some concrete implementation has been provided. The problem here is I am seeing lots of implementation classes when I try to search for the references. So in order to override debug method what should I do

Comment: Use public class MyLogger implements Logger {}. By doing this you can override any function of Logger.

Comment: I want the original implementation of debug method in place and on top of that implementation I want to do some changes. Had that been a class then I could have easily called the super.method(). But in case of interface, even when the implementation class is unknown, how do we override the same?

Comment: @AvniGarg You do not override. You hide. That is: your MyLogger class needs to implement the same Interface, in the respective method, do what you want to do, then call LOGGER.debug("Your meddeled with message").

Comment: @Fildor Tried doing the same. But looks like the hiding/overriding is not working.

Comment: @AvniGarg As Fildor said write your own function `myFunc{ //write all the logic you want; LOGGER.debug("Your meddeled with message") }`. Use function myFunc wherever you want.

Comment: Original class 

'public class MyLogger  {
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogger.class);
 public static org.slf4j.Logger init(Class clazz) {
        final Logger loggerOut = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
        setContainerId();
        LOGGER.debug("Logger is initialized for [{}].", clazz.getName());
        return loggerOut;
    }
 }'
Using this custom logger like :
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = MyLogger.init(MyController.class);
LOGGER.debug("My message");

Comment: Updated class:
public class MyLogger implements Logger {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogger.class);
 public static org.slf4j.Logger init(Class clazz) {
        final Logger loggerOut = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
        setContainerId();
        LOGGER.debug("Logger is initialized for [{}].", clazz.getName());
        return loggerOut;
    }
 
    
    public void debug(String msg, Object arg1)
    {
        LOGGER.debug("My message",arg1);
    }
}
I tried this but this way it did not work. Would appreciate help.

Comment: Could you please format the code and add it? It gets difficult to read.

Comment: Also please mention the consuming class code where you are using the above class instance.